# Problem in installing xcode

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have just installed xcode 3.2 on my Mac mini. the installer also shows "Installation successful". but when i search for 'Xcode' in spotlight , it doesnot show anything.
Can anyone have any clue for this??

Every help is appreciated

Thanks 
Puneet

Answer (score 0):

Look at /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: thanks dear, but it is not showing anything in /Developer/Applications